# Bundle install error: Source does not contain any versions of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

My gem file contains:

```
gem "breadcrumb", :git => "git@github.com:mjacobus/Breadcrumb.git"

gem "simple_menu", :git => "git@github.com:mjacobus/simple_menu.git"
```

The first gem installs as expected, but the second one fails.

```
Updating git@github.com:mjacobus/simple_menu.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Could not find gem 'simple_menu (>= 0) ruby' in git@github.com:mjacobus/simple_menu.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'simple_menu (>= 0) ruby'
```

Similar posts points to the lack of the .gemspec file, but this file exists. https://github.com/mjacobus/simple_menu/blob/master/simple_menu.gemspec

I am probably doing something stupid that someone else's eyes will be able to see.

## edit

I cloned the repo into the vendor/plugins folder and changed my Gemfile

```
gem "simple_menu", :path => "vendor/plugins/simple_menu"
```

Bundle install issues now the error:

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Could not find gem 'simple_menu (>= 0) ruby' in source at vendor/plugins/simple_menu.
Source does not contain any versions of 'simple_menu (>= 0) ruby'
```

## edit 2

I knew it was a stupid error. The gem name was not correct.

https://github.com/mjacobus/simple_menu/commit/1afca04b08a084dafb9bdf6e595a2bb9a7b7a55f

Comment: Would you please post your answer and mark it as the accepted answer? That will clear this question from the list of unanswered questions. Thanks!

Comment: thx, did the same, you saved me some time!

Comment: Thank you for the "edit 2" comment, made me double check and realized I did the same thing!!

Comment: Note also that the name is case-sensitive, so `s.name = "Foo"` won't work with `gem "foo"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gemspec file as named **simplemenu.gemspec** instead of **simple_menu.gemspec**.

Answer (score 26):

As Marcelo mentioned, I got same error and it was a stupid thing:

gemspec file

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
 s.name = 'niche_wir_theme' 
 ....
```

Gem file (include)

```
gem 'niche-wir-theme', :git => 
....
```

As you can see in my gemspec i named using ("_") underscore and on my gemfile i was trying to call it with "-" (dash)...

(palmface) so just take care of the name notation, the one you are declaring at gemspec file against the one you use for the call in the gem file of the other project are probably different

Answer (score 10):

I ran into a similar problem with Rails 4.2. In my case it was another stupid mistake. It appears that if you leave "TODO" or "FIXME" in the comments in gemspec file, it will reject that gem and will throw the same error.  Be sure to read the output of bundle command.

Comment: Annoyingly I read this answer and still didn't notice the "TODO" warning which caused the error until I scrolled back up the bundler output. Thanks.